# Change default Source-Control-Management for a project in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I'm using Eclipse 2019-03 with CDT. I imported multiple projects. All projects use SVN and git.

I use `Git integration for Eclipse` and `Subclipse`, `Subvcersion Client Adapter` and `SVNKit`.

In Eclipse some projects are SVN projects and some projects are Git projects. The differences are:

1. After right-click on a project -> Team:
   In SVN projects I can see the SVN options and in Git projects I can see git option.
2. In Project Explorer Git projects look different than SVN projects.
3. After right-click on a project -> Properties:
   SVN projects contain a menu entry for SubVersion and Git projects contain a menu entry for Git.

I'd like to convert all Git projects to SVN projects as this is currently our default SCM. Maybe later I want to convert all projects to Git. Is there a *correct* way without changing `.project` or `.cproject` files or renaming the `.git` folder? How does Eclipse choose if a project is a Git or a SVN project?

**EDIT:**
For one project I removed the `.git` folder and imported the project. The project was added as SVN project. Then I imported a copy of that project with `.git` folder. The project was added as Git project. I compared `.project` and `.cproject` and found no considerable differences. The I compared both projects in `.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources/.projects/`. The only two considerable differences are:

- In the SVN project the file `.indexes/properties.index` ends with `.org.tigris.subversion.subclipse.core.svnnature` and in the Git project it ends with `!org.eclipse.egit.core.GitProvider`
- Git projects contains a folder `org.eclipse.egit.core` with one file `GitProjectData.properties`. In my case this file only contains

  ```
  #GitProjectData
  #Mon May 06 17:03:12 CEST 2019
  .gitdir=../.git
  ```

I'm not sure if this information helps anybody but for me it's not clear how to change a project from one SCM to another.

Comment: It is not really clear what you are asking. Are those projects using _both_ Git and SVN at the same time, redundantly? Or are _some_ projects in Git and others in SVN? Just removing the `.git` or `.svn` folders won't change the project from one to the other, what you'd really have to do is create new repositories for those (e.g. with `git-svn` for SVN -> Git) and then probably re-import those into Eclipse.

Comment: All projects are using both Git and SVN at the same time. All projects contain a `.git` and a `.svn` folder. SVN is officially used in our company. Git is used in our teams. We use Git to share the code changes and we use SVN to commit code into build and deployment.

Comment: I think I just broke my Eclipse by installing Subclipse... My only idea would be to Team->Disconnect the project, and then Team->Share it again, selecting the other mode, but I can't test it now. Apart from that, I would not be surprised if noone ever considered this use case. You might have to use the command line for either Git or SVN.

Comment: I believe it is the `org.eclipse.team.core.repository` persistent variable for a project when determines what the project is. This can only be changed by plug-ins. I think that is the value you see in the properties.index

Comment: I will try it tomorrow and I'm sorry that you broke your Eclipse to try it out and to help me.

Comment: @greg-449 The line in `.indexes/properties.index` is `repository^@.org.tigris.subversion.subclipse.core.svnnature`. I didn't any plugin to manage the SCM of an project.

Comment: That is a binary file, it can only be modified using the Eclipse Java APIs.